# Google Script Won't Authorize

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script designed to operate on a raw spreadsheet and move data around to other sheets within the same workbook.  Every time I try to run it, I get "You do not have permission to call openByURL" despite the fact that I authorized the script to access google docs the first time I ran it.  When I go into my app permissions it shows as being authorized.  I am the owner of all the files concerned and am logged into my account.  Am I missing something here?

I have deleted and recreated the script multiple times, initializing it from various methods (triggers, custom menu, script editor "Run" menu) and authorizing it every time.  The same error persists.

Comment: How is this script being invoked? If it's through any path that executes it anonymously (custom function, for example), then your credentials aren't in use. Can you provide more info about how you're using it? And, ideally, the code in question.